# c# attribute to validate method parameters

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a windows service and I am passing in a userId to each of the service calls that is validated against the database. Right now I have to call that validation method in each of the  methods internally. I was trying to make a c# attribute that I could prefix each method with and have it do the validation for me but I'm not sure how to read the methods userId argument from the attribute.

This is what I have:

```
public int GetANumber(Guid userId){

ValidateUserId(userId);

return 1;

}
```

This is what I want:

```
[ValidateUserId]
public int GetANumber(Guid userId){

    return 1;

    }
```

This is what I have so far for my attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class ValidateUserId : Attribute
    {
        public ValidateUserId()
        {
            //need to get userId from method here and check against db
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a problem attributes are meant to address. Make a method call. Attribute values must be known at compile time.

Comment: You could probably do it with some sort of IL Weaving.  Maybe check out PostSharp....  Other than that, you would have to do some heavy reflection.  With that implementation, you would have to call a some sort of `PerformValidation` method at the start of each method.  Even then, I'm not sure how that would get the actual values used.  But really, don't.  Just call your method.

Comment: Methods shouldn't be cluttered with validation like this. If you need to do some sort of validation, put the User on thread static storage (or somewhere accessible) and don't pass it in to each method.